# Collections.sort throws UnsupportedOperationException while sorting a List after guava's Lists.transform function in Java?

Tags: java, guava

I have a list which I transform using guava's `Lists.transform` function. Later, when I try to sort the list using `Collections.sort()`, I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

My code look's like this:

```
private List<SelectItemInfo> convertToSelectItemList(
        final List<String> dataOwnersOfActiveQualifiers)
    {

        final List<SelectItemInfo> dataOwnersSelectItemList = transform(dataOwnersOfActiveQualifiers,
            new Function<String, SelectItemInfo>()
            {
                public SelectItemInfo apply(final String input)
                {
                    final Employee employee = getLdapQuery().findEmployeesByIdOrLogin(input);
                    return new SelectItemInfo(input, employee.toStringNameSurname());
                }
            });
        Collections.sort(dataOwnersSelectItemList, this.comparator);
        return dataOwnersSelectItemList;
    }
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: What is the actual List implementation of `dataOwnersSelectItemList` that is being returned?

Comment: Well, the [JavaDoc on `Lists.transform()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function-) states: `The add, addAll and set methods are unsupported in the returned list.` - and at least `set()` would be needed to sort a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections.sort needs to be able to call set on the list and have it do the expected thing. The list returned by transform doesn't support its set method (it's a "read only" list).

An easy fix is to create a new list and sort that

```
List<SelectItemInfo> sortedCopy = new ArrayList(dataOwnersSelectItemList);
Collections.sort(sortedCopy, this.comparator);
// use sortedCopy
```

Streams are a better solution

Comment: "Streams are a better solution" is too general an assertion for my taste. The execution models (generally speaking lazy, view collections of Guava vs. traversable once Stream) have different use cases. E.g. from a memory allocation point of view, Guava allocates nearly nothing, while a stream+filter+collect allocates more than double the space. Fine answer otherwise.

Comment: @GPI "allocates more than double the space" - where did you get that from? All I can see is that the `collect()` call allocates space analogous to `new ArrayList(<list transformed by Guava>)`, and the filter operations are lazy, one-element-at-a-time, and therefore also allocate virtually nothing, analogous to Guava's lazy operations.

Comment: `Collector.toList` collects to `ArrayList::new`, which basically is an array of size 10. When the 11th element is accumulated, the array has to be grown, which `ArrayList` does by allocating a new one of size 15 and copying everything back. When the 16th element arrives ? Another array (of size 22,  another full copy). When the 23rd comes along... All over. So to collect a 100 element list, you allocate at best one 100-sized array (which I mean by "double"), but you may allocate 10+15+22+33+49+73+109 sized-arrays ("more than double). Put that in a hot loop, and watch your GC having fun.

Comment: This is **not** to say that Streams are terrible. E.g. lazy views are terrible CPU-wise if you have to recompute them 10s of time. It just is a different tool, for a different use case.

Comment: @GPI I see what you mean. You can use `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(dataOwnersOfActiveQualifiers.size()))` so that it initializes the result list with exactly the required capacity. Granted it doesn't look quite as readable as Collectors.toList().

Comment: Yes you can, and if you know you are in a "hot" method, you probably should. Though, in case of filtering, you can not really know what to expect, and targetting an optimal size is hard. So I'm really only advocating here that there is a good use case for lazy views... The ability to have live updates (propagation of modifications from the underlying list to the view, and vice versa) is something streams are unsuitable for too.